# Making ANTLR4 Parse Tree Serializable

Tags: antlr4

Is it possible to save up the parse tree generated by ANTLR4? For example, by making ParseTree or its subclasses Serializable.

I'd like to use ANTLR4 to parse the source files in my project.  My project is quite large and contains hundreds of source files. Usually, I need to walk through the parse trees of several source files to get my desire info. The full grammar is quite huge and it takes a while to parse even just 1 source file.  So, it would be impractical to parse all the source files again every time I start my tool in order to get 1 piece of information (e.g. callers of a function).  It would be nice if I can just parse once and save the parser output into the hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having a problem with performance, you should make sure you are using the two-stage parsing strategy. For an example, look at the usage of the `TWO_STAGE_PARSING` field in the following test:

[TestPerformance.java](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/TestPerformance.java)

You can make a request regarding making `ParserRuleContext` serializable on the [ANTLR 4 issue tracker](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues).

PS: The next release of ANTLR (4.0.1) will contain additional performance improvements as well.

Comment: Link is wrong, now is https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool-testsuite/test/org/antlr/v4/test/tool/TestPerformance.java